# How to prove $x_{n+1}y_n-x_ny_{n+1}=2^{3n}\sqrt{7}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, induction

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let

$z_n=(1-i\sqrt {7})^n, ~x_n = Re~z_n,~y_n = Im~z_n$.

I want to show the following:

$x_{n+1}y_n-x_ny_{n+1}=2^{3n}\sqrt{7} ~~~(n \in \mathbb{N})$

My only idea was to show this using mathematical induction:

Basis: Show that the statement holds for n = 0.

$x_1y_0-x_0y_1=1 \cdot 0-(-\sqrt 7)=\sqrt 7= 2^{3\cdot 0}\sqrt{7}$

Inductive step: $n \rightarrow n+1$

Assume that it's true for n. Then one has:

$x_{n+2}y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}y_{n+2}=...$

How to go on?

Comment: write $x_n$ and $y_n$ as $\frac{z_n+\overline{z_n}}{2}$ and $\frac{z_n-\overline{z_n}}{2i}$ respectively. And then simplify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 
$${z_n}\overline{z_{n+1}}=(x_nx_{n+1}+y_ny_{n+1}) + i(x_{n+1}y_{n}-x_{n}y_{n+1})$$
you want to compute the imaginary part of $$ (1-i\sqrt 7)^n(1+i\sqrt 7)^{n+1}=\left((1-i\sqrt 7)(1+i\sqrt 7)\right)^n\cdot (1+i\sqrt 7).$$